# Find and replace multiple strings in file then output to new filename python

Tags: python, full-text-search, replace

I am looking to create a python script that will read one source file then produce another file with a string for the name.

for example

macaddress.cnf.xml contains the source file

I need to change '6000' to '6001' in multiple places of macaddress.cnf.xml, then I want to output to newmacaddress.cnf.xl.

This is what I have

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#read and write to file
f = open(file)
for line in f:
    if line.contains('66001'):
        newline = line.replace('66001', '60001')
```

To add I would like to be able to do this with a csv or whatever and have the script run through and do

60002 >> macaddressfromcsv.cnf.xml
60003 >> macaddressfromcsv.cnf.xml
60004 etc.

Sorry I am very new to this any help would be great.

Comment: Are you married to doing this in Python? You could use sed to do this.

Comment: use sed for simple substitution. Other than that, no, sed is not the appropriate tool.

Comment: @OP, you should show examples of your input file

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question what all of your goals are, but I will try to address some of them. If you want to take input from one file, modify it, and then write to another file you could do following:

```
buffer = "";
with open("input_file") as in:
    buffer = in.read();

# do modifications ...

with open("output_file", 'w') as out:
    out.write(buffer);
```

Note: you would need to use `from __future__ import with_statement` in python version 2.5.

To do multiple replacements you can actually use [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
buffer = re.sub('6000', '6001', buffer)
```

As to the the additional information using csv, please provide a more detailed explanation or an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: regex is not needed for his case.

Answer (score 0):

```
data=open("input_file").read()
outfile=open("macaddressfromcsv.cnf.xml","w")
for i in range(6001,6010):
    outfile.write(data.replace("6000",str(i))
    outfile.write("\n") # you may not need this
outfile.close()
```

Edit. I think you need to clarify the question. Is there only one output file or to you want one file per replacement?